The interval of Hyperbolic Space (Euclidean Anti-deSitter Space)
I am learning the Group Theory notes from G. Moore.
https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/618Spring2022/GTLect1-AbstractGroupTheory-2022.pdf
7.4.3 Orbits Of The Lorentz Group In $d > 2$ Dimensions As Homogeneous Spaces
As an example, he showed that the Orbit of the Lorentz group can be regard as a model of hyperbolic space and he tried to parametrize the orbits and get the metric (interval) like this
$$x^0=\lambda \cosh \theta$$
$$x^i=\lambda \sinh \theta n^i$$
$$ds^2=d\theta^2 + \sinh^2(\theta)ds^2_{S^{d-2}}$$
here he chose $\eta=(-1,1,1,1)$ as the metric tensor of Minkowski spacetime。
My question is how can we get $ds^2$ from the parametrize? As the definition of $$ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu,$$ I think the result above has lost some terms like $\cosh\theta\sinh\theta n^i d\theta d\tilde{x}^{i }$ ?

Mathematically, the metric $g$ on a manifold $\mathcal M$ induces a metric on the submanifold $\mathcal N$ just by restricting the metric $g_p: T*_p \mathcal M \otimes T*_p \mathcal M$ to the tangent space of $\mathcal N$ for every point $p \in \mathcal N$, i.e.,
$$\tilde g_p := g_p\vert_{T\mathcal N}: T^*_p \mathcal N \otimes T^*_p \mathcal N$$.
You need to write the metric in coordinates adapted to the submanifold and then neglect the $d\iota$ contributions of all one-forms that anihilate $T\mathcal N$.
